# Python function that capitalizes entire word

Tags: python, function, capitalize

So I have created a python function:

```
def capitalize(x):
  for a in x:
    a.capitalize()
  print x

capitalize("heey")
```

It is supposed to turn the argument "heey" into "HEEY". But it does not work. It prints "heey". What's up?

Comment: `str.capitalize` does not update the string in-place. You need to assign it back. Also note that you have `str.upper()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capitalize()` is not an in-place operation. It doesn't modify the original string but instead it returns the capitalized version. You need to save this value in a variable. For example, the following code:

```
a = "heey"
a.capitalize()
b = a.capitalize()
print("a = " + a)
print("b = " + b)
```

has output:

```
a = heey
b = Heey
```

also, if you're going to make all chars uppercase, just call `upper()` instead, but if you absolutely want to use `capitalize()` you can do this:

```
def capitalize(x):
    y = ""
    for a in x:
        y += a.capitalize()
    print(y)

capitalize("heey")
```

output:

```
HEEY
```

and here's a shorter version that does the same thing:

```
def capitalize(x):
    y = "".join([a.capitalize() for a in x])
    print(y)
```

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to make my function work using capitalize(). And if so, how would I rewrite the function to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler way:

```
def capitalize(x):
  print(x.upper())

capitalize("heey")
```

Output:

```
HEEY
```